AttributeError: 'QuantumCircuit' object has no attribute 'cnot' Receiving this error when using the qiskit.QuantumCircuit.cnot
def ans(n, depth):
    qc = QuantumCircuit(n)
    for j in range(depth):
        for i in range(n):
            param_name = f'theta_{j}_{i}'
            theta_param = Parameter(param_name)
            qc.rx(theta_param, i)
            qc.ry(theta_param, i)
            qc.rz(theta_param, i)
    for i in range(n):
        if i == n-1:
            qc.cnot(i, 0)
        else:
            qc.cnot(i, i+1)
    return qc

This method seems to be deprecated and removed. I got this error while trying to replicate the stock price prediction using Quantum circuits from THIS post.
I want an alternate function that has been given in the new version of qiskit

Found the documentation that talks about these deprecated methods for quantum gates.
for this specific method you can use the QuantumCircuit.cx instead of cnot.
Here's some more:
enter image description here
